# How sensitive is a timing belt or serpentine belt to getting a little oil on it?

Tags: oil, oil-change, timing-belt, motors, serpentine-belt

Every once in a while, a drop of motor oil will get on the timing belt or serpentine belt when adding motor oil.

Is it a good idea to wipe it off right away?

If so, even after wiping it off, some motor oil residue will remain on the belt.  Is this an issue?

Comment: Put a cloth or paper **before** pouring oil and avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it is not an issue.**

Serpentine belts are very tough. Motor oil will not harm any rubber in or around the engine.

Wipe it off to keep the engine bay clean.